# Batch operation for consuming data from API via drupal_http_request

Tags: batch-operations

I am consuming data from an API which provides a URL similar to:
**http://data.something.com/api/records?pageIndex=0&pageSize=25**

The API will return XML which I will then use to create nodes.
There are many thousands of records, so I will need to do this via batch. I have used batch before but never for drupal_http_request. What would be the best approach for this? Is batch API the best solution, or would another method be preferable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You're probably best off using the [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import from feeds it can do them as one off imports imports or periodic batch jobs and create nodes from the feeds automatically. Even though they're beta/alpha they're well used and actively developed.

Comment: Thanks, I've been fiddling with feeds, feeds_xpathparser and feeds_crawler. Just going through the docs.

Comment: Great. Tested and working.

Comment: Good stuff, glad I could help :)